# Excel VBA columns function fails: Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

When using VBA code to automate functionality in Microsoft Excel, I've encountered an apparent "bug" using the columns function (see code sample). Does anybody have an explanation as to why my code is failing?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim m_Range As Excel.Range
    Set m_Range = Me.Range("A1:I10")

    'Works as expected
    m_Range.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbCrimson

    'Works as expected
    m_Range.Columns(m_Range.Columns.Count + 1).Rows("1:3").Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRosyBrown

    Fails: Application-defined or object-defined error
    m_Range.Rows(m_Range.Rows.Count + 1).Columns("1:3").Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbAquamarine     
End Sub
```

Comment: Rows are numbered columns have letters. Therefore `.Columns("1:3")` can't work. Use  `.Columns("A:C")` instead. Or if you need to use numbers for columns use `.Columns(1).Resize(ColumnSize:=3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows are numbered columns have letters.

This is why `.Rows("1:3")` works as expected but `.Columns("1:3")` can't work. The correct syntax would be `.Columns("A:C")`.

If you need to use numbers for columns you can use `.Columns(1).Resize(ColumnSize:=3)` which means select column 1 and resize selection to 3 columns.

So this should work if you want to use numbers for columns:

```
m_Range.Rows(m_Range.Rows.Count + 1).Columns(1).Resize(ColumnSize:=3).Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbAquamarine
```

Or the following if letters are your choice:

```
m_Range.Rows(m_Range.Rows.Count + 1).Columns("A:C").Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbAquamarine
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
m_Range.Rows(m_Range.Rows.Count + 1).Columns("1:3").Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbAquamarine
```

To This

```
m_Range.Rows(m_Range.Rows.Count + 1).Columns("A:C").Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbAquamarine
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and quick response.